# How to load dynamic content into a DIV using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-load

I have a div:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

And when the page is loaded i call a `.load()`. This load takes around 10 minutes to finish and during the execution its PHP file return some information telling about the execution status, something like Linux loading. I want do put this information inside the div `#content` dynamically, but `.load()` is putting only at the end of the execution. Someone can help me please to do this?

The `.load()` call:

```
$("#content").load("/admin/ajax/analyse.php");
```

Comment: When you paste the same URL into a browser window, does it take 10 minutes?

Comment: @Diodeus, Yes, it is a little heavy

Comment: Then there's nothing you can do on the client-end to fix this. You need to re-factor how your server-side code works.

Comment: If you read here, http://api.jquery.com/load/ , you will see a function called "complete" documented. Put that function in the 3rd parameter on the call to 'load' and it will get called when the data is finished loading. The parameters will contain the data. Try some code and get back to us.

Comment: You should kick off a process and have other calls ping the server to get updates. You are not going to make a "websocket" with an http call. Maybe you should look into web sockets. ;)

Comment: @LeeMeador, I want to put the output dynamically, before the end of the execution

Comment: @LeeMeador You are missing the point. The OP wants to stream data down as the server returns it. Not one chunk.

Comment: So does the server generate the data line by line, so to speak? Does it generate some of the data, send it, generate some more, send some more and so forth? Does OP have control over the server? Can OP make changes to the way it works?

Comment: @LeeMeador, Yes, i receive data line by line. Yes, i have control over the server.

Comment: To add another question ... does the page load little by little, top to bottom when you paste the URL into a browser window?

Comment: @LeeMeador, When try to open the page in a browser i got the page little by little, inside the 10 minutos interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's ajax interface does not provide a way to get progress updates for a response (even though it claims to be a superset of the browser's native `XMLHttpRequest` object).  Apparantly, [such a use case is inconceivable to the jQuery developers](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

> No `onreadystatechange` mechanism is provided, however, since `success`, `error`, `complete` and `statusCode` cover all conceivable requirements.

By using the an `XMLHttpRequest` directly, you can read the current progress of a response in an `onreadystatechange` event handler:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/admin/ajax/analyse.php", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function receiveUpdate(e) {
    $("#content").html(this.responseText);
}
xhr.send();
```

This works in the latest versions of most browsers including IE 10, Chrome, and Firefox.

**Demos:**

- [Send response continually for 10 minutes](http://jumpingfishes.com/progresstest2.htm)
- [Pause several minutes between sending data over 15 minutes](http://jumpingfishes.com/progresstest3.htm)

Comment: It is working partly, after about 4 minutes it stops to receive the information about the execution status. Do you know what can be this?

Comment: @MarcioSimao - Works for me: http://jumpingfishes.com/progresstest2.htm.  Could it be your server?  If nothing is sent from your server for a long period of time, you won't receive any updates during that time.

Comment: Many thanks! I will analyze what is happening, maybe can be a server configuration. Anyway, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to address this, but all of them will require server-side changes. One solution (which I think best fits how you are imagining this to work) is [long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Ajax_with_long_polling).

See this [quesiton on long polling with PHP and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code).

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea that you would have to flush out ...

On the server,

1. a user hits URL #1,
2. a session is started if there isn't one already.
3. start an asynchronous process generating the data.
4. as it gets some part of the data finished, it gets queued up. More simply said, it puts the data in chunks somewhere. Could be a database of a cache in memory.
5. When all the data is generated by the asynchronous task, it sends over an end-of-file indication by using some magic string.

On the server also:

1. the same user hits URL #2 (and you know from the session info)
2. you give him a chunk of the data from the front of the queue.
3. every time he hits URL #2 you give him some more data.
4. when the browser requests one last time and all that is left is the end-of-file indication, the server can return some HTTP result code indicating no more data or it can return the magic string.

On the client side,

1. do your ajax request against URL #1 to start the server generating.
2. issue requests against URL #2 repeatedly.
3. Every result gets appended to the page element so the user can see it as it arrives.
4. When the client request returns the 'no more data' result code (or the magic end-of-file string), it quits requesting more data and signals to the user, by putting something on the screen showing that all the data is there.

That should work for you.